# I need to have a formula that will choose the Least value out of 3 cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I need to have a formula that will choose the least value out of 3 cells.

Cells are as follows with random numbers

```
I29=5

I30=10

I31=15
```

Currently I’m using

```
=rounddown(if(I29<I30,if(I29<I30,I29,I31),I30))
```

And the cells are as follows

```
I29=217

I30=304

I31=51
```

This formula works with the first set with `I29` coming out with the lowest number of 5, but with the current set comes out with `I29` sill coming out with the lowest number at 217, which is bigger than `I31` at 51

This formula is also set to take whatever number is chosen and round it down because I need whole numbers after the IF statement finds a number.Please help

Comment: Why not just use the built-in `MIN()` function?

Comment: Can you just give me an example fr my requirement?

Comment: In cell I32 put =MIN(I29:I31) display should show 5

Answer (score 2):

The MIN function takes a set of values or a cell range and returns the lowest value, so for your example you would use MIN(I29:I31), which will give the lowest of the values in the cells I29, I30 and I31.

By the way, the ROUNDDOWN function requires a second argument specifying how you want the value rounded; to get integers, use 0, e.g. ROUNDDOWN(MIN(I29:I31), 0).

See http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/excel-help/min-function-HP010062520.aspx and http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/excel-help/rounddown-function-HA102752881.aspx for more details.

Comment: Hey.. Thank you so much for the info.Much appreciated.

Comment: You're welcome. If this answered your question please mark it as "accepted".